# EF Core 5 or 6, how to select all related products based on mutual categories

Tags: performance, linq, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, many-to-many

I have a many-to-many relationship between `Products` and `Categories`, I want to select all the related products (by any mutual categories) in EF Core 5, 6.

I can add all the products by each mutual category by looping on product categories and then distinct them, but this is not a nice solution at all, I am sure there is a single EF Linq query for this job.

Relation is like this:

```
Products - ProductInCategories - Categories
```

```cs
var allProducts = Product.ProductInCategories
                         .SelectMany(t => t.Category.ProductInCategories)
                         .Select(t => t.Product)
                         .Distinct().ToList();
```

This is neither nice nor efficient, please let me know the best solution.

Comment: Your query selects all products which have category, why not just select from Products table?

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv I don't want mutual categories themselves, I just want a list on products which has at least one category in common.

Comment: My code actually works, but I'm looking for a nicer and more efficient solution.

Comment: `Distinct` is a sign that something is wrong. `allProducts = _context.Product.Where(p => p.Category != null).ToList();`. You have not shown your model (why?) so I assume you have `Category` navigation property.

Answer (score 0):

For select all the products with related categories:

```
var allProducts = _context.Product.Include(a => a.ProductInCategories)
                                    .ThenInclude(a => a.Category)
                                    .ToList();
```

For select all the products with specific category(e.g. which category id equals to 1):

```
var allProducts = _context.Product.Include(a => a.ProductInCategories)
                                    .ThenInclude(a => a.Category)
                                    .Where(a => a.ProductInCategories.Any(c => c.CategoryId == 1))
                                    .ToList();
```

If you just want to select the specific products without displaying the related category:

```
var allProducts = _context.Product
                           .Where(a => a.ProductInCategories.Any(c => c.CategoryId == 1))
                           .ToList();
```

Comment: I think this code is even less efficient than mine, in addition, I don't have the category, I just have a product which has many categories

Comment: Hi @Mertez, what do you mean you don't have category?

Comment: This is the ShowProduct page, I have the product itself, the product is related to many categories so I have maybe 3-4 categories related to that product, I want to show the other products as "Related Products" which has at least 1 category in common with this specific product.